# Filter array and reset the index too

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "Peter",
    age: 20,
    nationality: "American", 
    index: 0
  },
  {
    name: "David",
    age: 25,
    nationality: "English", 
    index: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Gabriel",
    age: 23,
    nationality: "Spanish", 
    index: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Kate",
    age: 22,
    nationality: "English", 
    index: 3
  },
];
```

If I want to return a new array with only the people with English nationality I'd use `filter`, like this:

```
let englishPerson = data.filter(el => el.nationality === 'English');
console.log(englishPerson);
```

And this will log the following:

```
> Array [Object { name: "David", age: 25, nationality: "English", index: 1 }, Object { name: "Kate", age: 22, nationality: "English", index: 3 }]
```

But I would like to reset the index after the data is filtered, so the first object in the new filtered array should have an index of 0, second an index of 1 and so on. In this case David has an index of 1, because it kept the same index from the original data.

Comment: Why store the index separately? Why not use the array's built-in indexing?

Answer (score 3):

You could `filter` followed by `map`, but it would be better to do it in one go with `reduce` - if the item passes the test, add it to the accumulator, with the `index` of the accumulator's current length:

```js
const data=[{name:"Peter",age:20,nationality:"American",index:0},{name:"David",age:25,nationality:"English",index:1},{name:"Gabriel",age:23,nationality:"Spanish",index:2},{name:"Kate",age:22,nationality:"English",index:3},]

console.log(
  data.reduce((a, item) => {
    if (item.nationality === 'English') {
      a.push({
        ...item,
        index: a.length
      });
    }
    return a;
  }, [])
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to modify the `index` property  of the filtered result:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Peter",
    age: 20,
    nationality: "American", 
    index: 0
  },
  {
    name: "David",
    age: 25,
    nationality: "English",
    index: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Gabriel",
    age: 23,
    nationality: "Spanish", 
    index: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Kate",
    age: 22,
    nationality: "English", 
    index: 3
  },
];

let i=0;
let englishPerson = data.filter(el => el.nationality === 'English').map(el => {
  el.index = i; i++;
  return el;
});
console.log(englishPerson);
```

Updated answer based on your comments:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Peter",
    age: 20,
    nationality: "American", 
    index: 0
  },
  {
    name: "David",
    age: 25,
    nationality: "English",
    index: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Gabriel",
    age: 23,
    nationality: "Spanish", 
    index: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Kate",
    age: 22,
    nationality: "English", 
    index: 3
  },
];

let i=0;
let englishPerson = data.filter(el => el.nationality === 'English').map(el => {
  if(el.hasOwnProperty('index')){
    el.index = i; i++;
  }
  return el;
});
console.log(englishPerson);
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I had no idea I could change methods like that, thank you!

Comment: if the objects didn't have the index property, could I achieve the same? I ask this because objects in an array still have an index regardless.

Comment: @Gilbert, yes, of course you will have the `index` property if it is not there in the array.......

Comment: Ok I didn't explain myself, I don't wish to add an index property at all in the filtered array, I just want to "reset" the index of the objects of the new array.

Comment: @Gilbert, do you mean you want to reset the `index` only if it is there in the array?

Comment: My issue is that I have an array of objects `data`, the objects look like this: `{
    product: "Swing Dress",
    url: "swingdress.html",
    image: "img/swing-dress.jpg",
    altDesc: "Dress",
    price: "$218.00",
    category: "dresses"
  }` I have like 40 of them, when I filter the array based on the objects category, the objects of the new filtered array `filteredData` keep the index of the previous array `data`, I'd like to restart the index of the objects for the new filtered array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176501/discussion-between-mamun-and-gilbert).

Answer (score 0):

If you want use your solution, with the slightest change, you can try this:

```
var c=0;
var englishPerson=data.filter(function(el){
    return el.nationality=="English" && (el.index=c++)>-1;
});
console.log(englishPerson);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use from `filters.tags.data.map(f => f.Key).toString()` replace filter.
Where you use from the map, that index been reset.

For example:

```
  $scope.ret = function(){
  data: url,
  method: post,
  retuen filters.tags.data.map(f => f.Key).toString();
 }
```

Comment: Add a minimal example to support your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Peter",
    age: 20,
    nationality: "American", 
    index: 0
  },
  {
    name: "David",
    age: 25,
    nationality: "English", 
    index: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Gabriel",
    age: 23,
    nationality: "Spanish", 
    index: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Kate",
    age: 22,
    nationality: "English", 
    index: 3
  },
];

data.filter(el => Object.values(el).includes('English')).forEach((obj, i) => {obj.index = i; console.log(obj)})
```

If you want to go with `map`, then just replace `forEach`with `map`!